# Counting strictly increasing and non-decreasing functions

Tags: combinatorics, functions

$f$ is non-decreasing if $x \lt y$ implies $f(x) \leq f(y)$ and increasing if $x < y$ implies $f(x) < f(y)$.

> - How many $f: [a]\to [b]$ are nondecreasing?
> - How many $f: [a] \to [b]$ are strictly increasing?

Where $[a]=\{1,2\ldots a\}$ and $[b]=\{1,2\ldots b\}$

Comment: You write a "real function," but what do you mean?  Usually, $[n]$ denotes the set of positive integers up to and including $n$.  Presumably, if you're counting them, then you want integer valued functions of integers.  Can you clarify what the notation $[n]$ means in your question?

Comment: @SammyBlack The OP simply defines increasing and nondecreasing for real functions. Then he/she applies this terminology to this particular case.

Comment: Well I think reduces to the amount of functions which preserve a partial ordering on the sets, are there some nice resulsts for that ?

Comment: That's true, @julien.  I'm just encouraging a new user to ask a question clearly.

Comment: @SammyBlack@julien: Thank you for all your comments and responses. Indeed, I am fairly new to this site and welcome all constructive criticism and remarks. Thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

Strictly increasing is easy: we need to **choose** the $n$ items in $[k]$ that will be the range of our function.

Comment: "Strictly" increasing...you're french, André Nicolas!

Comment: @AndreNicolas: your implication is that the number of increasing functions is $\binom{k}{n}$? or am i misinterpreting? Thank u.

Comment: @Dome: You are interpreting correctly. We should add the condition $k\ge n$, although that is not strictly necessary, since there is a common convention that if $k$ and $n$ are positive with $k\lt n$, then $\binom{k}{n}=0$.

Comment: @julien: I’m not French, but I avoid *increasing* in favor of the unambiguous *strictly increasing* and *non-decreasing*.

Comment: @julien: I was indeed born in France, but sadly after elementary school the mathematics was mostly in other languages, mainly English.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott If you were French, you would have a hard time accepting to say non-decreasing, which, unlike nonpositive, does not make sens on the logical level. But I got used to it...

Comment: @julien: Why do you think that *non-decreasing* doesn’t make sense on the logical level? To me it says exactly what’s wanted.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott My prhasing was unfortunate...I certainly did not mean that French people are more rigorous with logic...Simply, we distinguish increasing and strictly decreasing from an early age, so it is hard to get used to another convention.

Comment: @julien: Ah, that’s another (and perfectly understandable) matter. Like my difficulty with the (mostly French) convention that *compact* includes *Hausdorff*!

Comment: @BrianM.Scott For instance $f(x)=|x|$ is not increasing on $\mathbb{R}$. Yet it is not "nonincreasing". "Not increasing" is not equivalent to "nonincreasing". Agreed with compact+Hausdorff. I did not like that when a French student.

Comment: @julien: Okay, now I see what you’re thinking; I simply automatically interpret *non-* in that context as *never-*, and then it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

For the first part if you know how many of each of the $i\in [k]$ there are the on image of a non decreasing function, then only that function can have that property. Therefore the number of non deacreasing functions is on $1-1$ correspondance with the number of the solution.

$$x_1+x_2+\ldots x_k=n$$
**An example of that correspondance**
For instance for $n=5$ and $k=7$, if you know that in the image of $f$ there are two $1$,
two $3$, and one $7$. Then the only function with that property (which is non-decreasing) is:
\begin{align}
f(1)=1\\
f(2)=1\\
f(3)=2\\
f(4)=2\\
f(5)=7
\end{align}

Comment: @Dome: In other words, it’s really a disguised stars-and-bars problem.